# Microsoft Access take variable, cross check on other table, return if empty

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I currently have two tables: one table with all the user names, and one table with all shipping information.

**TABLE 1 - Usernames:** (~50 usernames)

Columns: username, full_name, email

**TABLE 2 - Shipping:** (~100 shipping info):

- Columns: username, shipping id

I'm trying to do the following:
take the 50 usernames stored in table 1, check each username against table 2, see if the username exists within table 2 (aka check whether user has made a shipping order). Return all usernames, full_name, and email of the users who have not made a shipment.

How would this be achieved in Access? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way is by using `not in` in the `where` clause:

```
select *
from usernames u
where u.username not in (select username from shipping)
```

I also think that this form is a clean way of writing the query, because it reads a lot like the problem you are trying to solve.